# Rendering template with json params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `new` and `create` actions like this:

```
def new
 @foo = Foo.new
end

def create
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
  respond_to do |format|
     if @foo.save
       format.html { redirect_to root_path }      
     else
       format.html { render :new } //**this line I want to send params**
     end
  end
end
```

I have a jbuilder file to new action like this:

**new.json.jbuilder**

```
json.foo do
  json.a "Some important info"
  json.b "Some important info"
end
```

And rails can't read this file after create's validation fails. How to render a view template (like `render :new`) and send some json data in this view?

I have a js calling like this:

```
var json_url = window.location.href + ".json";

var foo;

$.ajax({
  url: json_url,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    foo = data.foo;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Rails to render a file, you'll need to remove the call to `redirect_to` as it will effectively prevent any rendering.
Furthermore, if you don't want the controller to respond to different formats, it's better to skip the call to `respond_to`, too.

If you just call `render action: :new`, the view template will have access to all controller instance variables (like `@foo`):

```
json.foo do
  json.a @foo.a
  json.b @foo.b
end
```

Comment: Sorry I tried 'render action: :new' instead of using respond_to and I couldn't access new jbuilder template